# How to deal with incomplete JSON/Record types (IE missing required fields which I'll later fill in)?

Tags: haskell, yesod, aeson

EDIT: For those with similar ailments, I found this is related to the "Extensible Records Problem", something I will personally research more into.

---

EDIT2: I have started to solve this (weeks later now) by being pretty explicit about data types, and having multiple data types per semantic unit of data. For example, if the database holds an `X`, my code has an `XAction` for representing things I want to do with an `X`, and `XResponse` for relaying `X`s to an http client. And then I need to build the supporting code for shuttling bits between instances. Not ideal, but, I like that it's explicit, and hopefully when my models crystallize, it shouldn't really need much up keep, and should be very reliable.

---

I'm not sure what the correct level of abstraction is for tackling this problem (ie records? or Yesod?) So I'll just lay out the simple case.

### Simple Case / TL;DR

I want to decode a request body into a type

`data Comment = Comment {userid :: ..., comment :: ...}`

but actually I don't want the request body to contain `userid`, the server will supply that based on their Auth Headers, (or wherever I want to get data to default fill a field).

So they actually pass me something like:

`data SimpleComment = SimpleComment {comment :: ...} deriving (Generic, FromJSON)`

And I turn it into a `Comment`. But maintaining both nearly-identical types simultaneously is a hassle, and not DRY.

How do I solve this problem?

---

### Details on Problem

I have a record type:

`data Comment = Comment {userid :: ..., comment :: ...}`

I have a POST route:

```
postCommentR :: Handler Value
postCommentR = do
  c <- requireJsonBody :: (Handler Comment)
  insertedComment <- runDB ...
  returnJson insertedComment
```

Notice that the Route requires that the user supply their `userid` (in the `Comment` type, which is at least redundant since their id is associated with their auth headers. At worst, it means I need to check that users are adding their own id, or throwing away their supplied id, in which case why did they supply it in the first case.

So, I want a record type that's `Comment` minus `userid`, but I don't know how to do that intelligently.

---

### My Current (awful but working) Solution

So I made a custom type with derived `FromJSON` (for the request body) which is almost completely redundant with the `Comment` type.

`data SimpleComment = SimpleComment {comment :: ...} deriving (Generic, FromJSON)`

Then my new route needs to decode the request body according to this, and then merge a `SimpleComment` with a `userid` field to make it a `Comment`:

```
postComment2R :: Handler Value
postComment2R = do
  c <- requireJsonBody :: (Handler SimpleComment)
  (uid, _) requireAuthPair
  insertedComment <- runDB $ insertEntity (Comment { commentUserid  = uid
                                                   , commentComment = comment c})
  returnJson ...
```

Talk about boilerplate. And my use case is more complex than this simple `Comment` type.

If it factors in, you might be able to tell, I'm using the **Yesod Scaffolding**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution I like is to use a wrapper for things that come from/go to the DB:

```
data Authenticated a = Authenticated
  { uid :: Uid
  , thing :: a
  } deriving (Show)
```

Then you can have `Comment` be just `SimpleComment` and turn it into an `Authenticated Comment` once you know the user id.

Comment: ah, nice, but could there not be a more generalized pattern like this? Ex what if the data isn't about uid, but some other arbitrary thing? (I actually like your idea though since that covers some large percent of use cases)

Comment: I'm sure you could generalise this in many directions, perhaps at the cost of making it slightly harder to work with.

Comment: It is similar to what is done at the database level, by Persistent. You can read some explanation here http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent#persistent_insert

Comment: @Jean-BaptistePotonnier thanks for pointing that out. That clarifies a bit, but doesn't quite answer the case of relational data, IE when an object has an ID, and it's owner's ID. Or maybe it does answer that case, but I don't see it yet :)

Answer (score 3):

What I usually do to  get a type minus a field is just to have a function which take that field and return the type. In your case you just need to declare an JSON instance for `UserId -> Comment`. Ok it doesn't seem natural and you have to go it manually but it actually works really well, especially as there is only one field of type UserId  in Comment.

Comment: I like where this is going. Using your idea could I provide a FromJSON instance (`String -> Comment`) that could work for either Comment, and Comment minus UID?

Comment: This answer is old as the hills, but I'm wondering if you could share your FromJSON instance for a function like this?  I like this idea but am struggling to implement it.

Comment: I don't remember the exact syntax to parse json but you could do something along `parseJson (Object v) = \user -> User <$> (pure user) <*> v .: "thing"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for a nice way to solve this. :-)

What I usually do in my code is to operate directly on the Aeson's type `Value`. This is some of the sample code taken from my current project:

```
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as HM

removeKey :: Text -> Value -> Value
removeKey key (Object xs) = Object $ HM.delete key xs
removeKey _ ys = ys
```

I directly operate on the value `Object` and remove the particular key present in the javascript object.

And in the Yesod handler code, I do this processing:

```
myHandler :: Handler RepJson
myHandler = do
    userId <- insert $ User "sibi" 23
    guser <- getJuser user
    let guser' =  removeKey "someId" $ toJSON guser
    return $ repJson $ object [ "details" .= guser' ]
```

In some cases, I actually want to add some specific key to the outgoing JSON object. For those, I have specific helper functions defined which operate on the type `Value`. While this is not perfect, it has been helping me to avoid a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: I like this. So sometimes I need to decode a "type minus a field", such as when a user POSTs a Comment minus an ID, how do you derive the FromJSON for "Comment minus ID"?

Comment: @Josh.F There is no deriving involved here. There is only one original type involved. I remove or add a specific key using my helper functions.

Comment: @Sibi, it's a compromise I don't want to do. I think it's loosing too much type safety and declarativity, I mean having to read the handler code to see what data is used is something I don't want when using Haskell.